# How to organize the directory of a basic website

Tags: html, hosting, organization

I've got a basic website, 100% frontend. It resides in a folder somewhere on my computer during development, and will be hosted on a free webhost. The index.html is in the main directory. There's also a css, js, img folder in the main dir. Because this is a Windows PC, this folder is not the root directory (C:) and I'd rather not have my website in the root dir.

I've noticed that if I put a url in a css stylesheet located in C:\filepath\mainprojectfolder\css\, like so

```
background: url("img/image1.jpg");
```

This is interpreted as C:\filepath\mainprojectfolder\css\img\image1.jpg (Interpreted as starting from the same folder that the stylesheet resides in), when the actual file is in \mainprojectfolder\img\image1.jpg, and having `url("/img/image1.jpg")` will be interpreted as C:\img\image1.jpg

How do I properly organize my website directory? Is there a standard for this? I have no idea how this works on an actual web server, but since this is a simple website, I'd expect that this works the same on both my regular computer and a webhost.

Answer (score 0):

1. Project Folder

   - html files *You put the html files in the project folder not a dedicated html folder*

     - css folder
     - javascript folder
     - fonts folder
     - images or img folder

hope that works

Comment: The index.html file is located in C:\filepath\mainprojectfolder\index.html, the css file is in C:\filepath\mainprojectfolder\style.css, and the image file is in \mainprojectfolder\img\image1.jpg.

Comment: create a folder called css & put your style.css file in that folder, then just add in your css link `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">`